# Responsive thumbnail slider moving image one by one

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have created responsive thumbnail slider in my website to move images one by one instead of moving all the images at  a time.I have displayed 4 images in a row and it should move one by one by one but it is moving all the 4 images at a time.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div  class="carousel carousel-showmanymoveone slide" id="carousel123">                           
        <div class="carousel-inner carousel-inner2" role="listbox">                           
            <div class="item active images2">                                               
                <div class=" col-sm-3 ">
                    <a href="#" >
                        <img src="images/doctor1.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-responsive slider" width="170" height="201">
                    </a>
                    <div class="carousel-caption dctrss">
                        <h3 class="heading-caption">Doctor1</h3>
                        <p>( Orthopedician )</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item images2">
                <div class="col-sm-3 ">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/doctor2.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-responsive slider" width="170" height="201">
                    </a>
                    <div class="carousel-caption dctrss">
                        <h3 class="heading-caption">Doctor2</h3>
                        <p>( Orthopedician )</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item images2">
            <div class="col-sm-3  ">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/doctor3.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-responsive slider">
                </a>
                <div class="carousel-caption dctrss">
                    <h3 class="heading-caption">Doctor3</h3>
                    <p>( Orthopedician )</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item images2">
            <div class="col-sm-3   ">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/doctor4.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-responsive slider">
                </a>
                <div class="carousel-caption dctrss">
                    <h3 class="heading-caption">Doctor4</h3>
                    <p>( Orthopedician )</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--/row-->
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>              
</div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle link : `http://jsfiddle.net/1gntmoy8/1/`

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using this as example

https://www.bootply.com/PMDIAzc1Qo